# How to scroll up and look at data in GNU screen

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I am using a mac (snow leopard). I am a ruby on rails developer and I watched a screencast on GNU screen and am trying it out. So far I like it.

On a window when I start server I get to see the log messages. However I can't seem to scroll up. I do get a scroll bar. However when I use the scroll bar and scroll up I don't see anything.

How do people use GNU screen and scroll up?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a 'copy mode' in screen, activated by pressing, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, followed by <kbd>[</kbd>.  This gives you a cursor that you can use to scroll backwards.

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a faster way to go up rather than just having the up arrow pressed.

Comment: @dorelal: The vim-like shortcuts `Ctrl-U` and `Ctrl-D` move up a half page and down a half page while in copy mode.  Also, `ESC` will take you out of copy mode.

Comment: @dorelal I usually use the other shortcut ctrl-A, then Esc quickly, to get into copy mode rather than [.  It is easier for me to remember.

Comment: What's this *quickly?*  It does not seem to matter how fast you do it...

Comment: @kevin: quite right, the "quickly" was meant to explicitly convey "not simultaneously".

Comment: Isn't piping the output to less also an option, or am I missing something?

Comment: @VicGoldfeld Yes, that is also an option, but this works even after you forgot to pipe the output, so it's still useful.

Comment: But this remains annoying... see the next two answers for much more elegant solutions...

Answer (score 17):

Add the following to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
termcapinfo xterm ti@:te@
termcapinfo xterm-color ti@:te@
```

This will let you use the Terminal.app scrollbar instead of relying on screen's scrollback buffer.

Comment: This should really become a default setting. I keep on coming back here to get this, thanks!

Comment: ....And again.... and again... the gift that keeps on giving...

Comment: ...And again...

Comment: Or: `termcapinfo xterm* ti@:te@` for both.

Comment: It doesn't work with SHIFT+PgUp, so I still can't scroll up the terminal.

Comment: A downside is that the terminal's scroll may be much more limited than screen's.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way is to use the copy mode, as [Babu pointed out](https://superuser.com/q/138748/150988#138755).

You could speed things up a bit by automatically entering into copy mode when you press your favourite scroll keys.

For example, using PgUp and PgDown:

```
# easier scroll
bindkey "^[[5~" eval 'copy' 'stuff ^b'  # PgUp   | Enter copy/scrollback mode and page up
bindkey "^[[6~" eval 'copy' 'stuff ^f'  # PgDown | Enter copy/scrollback mode and page down
```

Comment: `bindkey` is the solution, but binding [Page Up] or [Page Down] will interfere with using `less`. We just need one key to enter `copy mode`. For completeness: To bind the [Insert] key (otherwise useless and right besides the navigation keys) with `copy mode`, we should add `bindkey -k kI copy` to `.screenrc` and restart the screen session.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [GNU Screen: Working with the Scrollback Buffer](https://web.archive.org/web/20130729074044/http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/) for a good introduction.

Comment: And... it's gone.  404

Comment: Replaced link with archive.org link

Answer (score 6):

- I use **Ctrl+A Esc** to go in copy mode.
- Then use **arrows** or **PageUp/PageDown** to move through the scroll buffer.
- To exit copy mode, just hit **Esc**.

that’s a little more intuitive by this way.