# GNU Screen: Better way to cut and paste?

Tags: gnu-screen, cut-and-paste

I've been using GNU Screen for close to 3 years and find it immensely useful. For such a robust and flexible program I find its cut and paste functionality a little basic.

Has anyone found a better way to use the cut and paste features besides the default settings? These include:

- Better cut/paste and hardstatus integration
- More recall than only the previously cut text
- Easier keybindings

Comment: I'm not confident this has anything to do with programming.

Comment: Screen has cut and paste? I just use the copy/paste features of my terminal program.

Comment: if you ask one single specific question you might get an answer.  this is all over the map, and any one of these might take a long time to give a good answer to.

Comment: @GregHewgill Read [this question and its answers](http://superuser.com/questions/138748/how-to-scroll-up-and-look-at-data-in-gnu-screen)  for more about scrolling, copying & pasting in screen

Comment: @DougHarris: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614/gnu-screen-survival-guide/70765#70765 for the commands that I actually use in screen. Turns out I use the "copy" feature for scrollback, but not copying.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my `/etc/screenrc` for setting I prefer.

Here are the lines related to the `hardstatus`.

```
hardstatus on
backtick 1 3600 1 /bin/uname -n
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{= dg} %-Lw%{+b}%n+%f %t%{-}%+Lw%< %=[%1` %l] [%0c]"
```

I still use the default keybindings, but these can also be changed in the configuration file.
The main resource are `man screen` (for shortcuts and the configuration file) and the web for the examples.

Some mnemonics for default shortcuts:

- `c-a c-c` create
- `c-a c-n` next
- `c-a c-p` previous
- `c-a c-d` detach
- `c-a x` where `x` is [0-9] goes to the screen x
- `c-a [` copy
- `c-a ]` paste

Answer (score 0):

I've simply avoided it or dug out the manual if I had to use it. I don't think [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) fares any better when it comes to c&p either.

Answer (score 0):

Both recall and keybindings can be changed in your .screenrc, which should be found in your home folder (~), if you don't have one you should be able to copy one from /etc/skel